# Is $f$ irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x], \mathbb Q [x], \mathbb Z[i][x], \mathbb Q [i][x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, gaussian-integers

> Let $f=2x^{32}+12x^{23}+18x^9+6 \in \mathbb Z[x]$. Is $f$ irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x], \mathbb Q [x], \mathbb Z[i][x], \mathbb Q [i][x]$

Let $a_i$ - coefficient for $x^i$. Then $a_0=6, a_9=18, a_{23}=12, a_{32}=2$.

For $p=3$ we have that $f$ is irreductible in $\mathbb Q(\mathbb Z)[x]$ from Eisenstein's criterion.

However I don't know how to 
consider task cases.

Comment: No, $f=2g$ is reducible over $\Bbb Z[x]$ since $2$ is not a unit.

Comment: Irreducibility, as all definitions, can be non-universal. Some people call a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ irreducible, when it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. You need to check which is the case in your case.

Comment: No, the definition of irreducible polynomial is unique, see wikipedia. Compare also with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72503/why-is-this-polynomial-irreducible-over-mathbbzi?rq=1), and the polynomial $6X$ in the comments.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Amen! Except that it is not.

Comment: tora, do you have a link for me? I only know one definition, I am sorry. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element) says "In abstract algebra, a non-zero non-unit element in an integral domain is said to be irreducible if it is not a product of two non-units."

Comment: @DietrichBurde I only use the definition that is not the one that I mentioned. However, there are some books that use it as I wrote. Definitions are not mathematics. Mathematics happens once the definitions are set. That is why they should check their source to see what is relevant in their case.

Comment: @tora We also have the [Gaus Lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_Lemma_on_Irreducible_Polynomials), where we can see why we need this. The key is that the polynomial needs to be *primitive* so that your assumption can hold. Perhaps you have assumed this.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Wikipedia is awful as a source, but well, even there they [mention it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial#Definition).

Comment: Where do they mention it there? For $F$ is a field, so not $\Bbb Z$. And $2$ is non-invertible in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Of course not in the beginning. The definition that I mentioned is, in my experience, uncommon. Although not unheard of. It is mentioned in the last sentence. Why some people have so much trouble understanding that there is nothing universal about definitions. This is like one time someone arguing that the empty space is not irreducible (in algebraic geometry it usually isn't, while in many topology books it is).

Comment: @DietrichBurde And to be clear, I don't use the definition that I mentioned. I only mentioned it just in case, because potentially newuser458 could be dealing with it, to make them aware of that detail.

Comment: @tora Yes, I know. I was just surprised because I never heard such a definition. That was as you would have told me, "a prime number is not universally defined. In my definition, $12$ can be a prime number". I think people very often forget that irreducibility in $\Bbb Z[x]$ and $\Bbb Q[x]$ are only equivalent for primitive polynomials. So I simply suspect an error.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am sorry, but your exchange of opinion caused me even more confusion in my head and I still do not know how to solve this task

Comment: @tora I am sorry, but your exchange of opinion caused me even more confusion in my head and I still do not know how to solve this task

Comment: Opinion? It is not a matter of opinion. If it were by my opinion everyone would define irreducible as not a multiple of two non-units (non-invertibles). So, start by finding in your text, course, or source, what is the definition of irreducible that you are using.

Comment: In my definition, not unit element $a \in  R \backslash 0$ (where R is a ring) is irreductible if and only if from equality $a=bc$ follows that $b$ is not unit or $c$ is not unit

Comment: @tora Given the context, explicitly asking for the irreducibility in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ and $\Bbb{Q}[x]$, it seems quite clear that this is not the definition of irreducibility over $\Bbb{Z}$ that is used here.

Comment: I've replaced the Eisenstein integers tag with the Gaussian integers tag. The Eisenstein integers are elements of $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$, where $\omega=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Here is a reference for the Eisenstein integers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part One: $\Bbb{Z}[x]$**

Let $g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{2}=x^{32}+6x^{23}+9x^9+3$.

Note that $g(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ by Eisenstein's criterion with the prime $p=3$.

The polynomial $2$ is also irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ because the units of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ are $\pm1$, and if you write $2=p(x)\cdot q(x)$ for some $p(x),q(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$, then one of $p(x)$, $q(x)$ must be a unit.

So $f(x)$ is not irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, but $f(x)=2\cdot g(x)$, and both $2$ and $g(x)$ are irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

**Part Two: $\Bbb{Q}[x]$**

Since $g(x)$ is primitive (i.e. the coefficients of $g(x)$ have no common factor) and irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, it follows by Gauss's lemma that $g(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

Since $2$ is a unit in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$, it follows that $f(x)=2\cdot g(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

**Part Three: $\Bbb{Z}[i][x]$**

Part three will be similar to part one, because $3$ is prime in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. This is based on the following characterization of the primes in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$:

**Theorem:** Let $a+bi\in\Bbb{Z}[i]$. Then $a+bi$ is a prime in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ iff one of the following is true:

(1) $a=0$ and $b\equiv3$ modulo $4$,

(2) $b=0$ and $a\equiv3$ modulo $4$,

(3) $a\ne0$, $b\ne0$ and $a^2+b^2$ is a prime in $\Bbb{Z}$.

It follows by Eisenstein with the prime $p=3$ that $g(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}[i][x]$.

Note that in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, we have that $2=(1-i)\cdot(1+i)$, and that $1-i$ and $1+i$ are prime in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. Hence in $\Bbb{Z}[i][x]$ we can factor $f(x)$ into irreducibles as follws:

$$f(x)=(1-i)\cdot(1+i)\cdot g(x).$$

**Part Four: $\Bbb{Q}(i)[x]$**

Since $g(x)$ is primitive and irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}[i][x]$, it follows by Gauss's Lemma that $g(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(i)[x]$.

Hence $f(x)=2\cdot g(x)$ is also irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(i)[x]$.

Comment: Will there person who downvoted my solution please provide feedback?

Comment: Probably one of the gang that begs for people asking to offer human sacrifices before they can get an aswer. When a question gets answered they lose all leverage, so they lash out in the only way they can.

Comment: I thought it might be because of some typos I had. There were a few places where I wrote $\Bbb{Q}(x)$ when I should have written $\Bbb{Q}[x]$. If anyone can find a typo or a mistake, please let me know.